# Heroku keeps deleting online added data

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed a django project on **heroku**.

For media storage, I used **aws s3 storage**.

The project has an admin interface, from which I can add data.

The problem is that,  after some time,  the data I added **online on heroku** is lost.

Only the **original data** (that was in my database before deploying on heroku ) is conserved.

I'm using heroku only for test, but still this is bothering.

Is there's a way to overcome this behaviour?

I though about storing data also in **aws s3** but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using your local `.sqlite3` to store the data, it will indeed reset every time. What I would suggest you to do is to make use of the [Heroku postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), and migrate your data to the heroku postgresql server. That way you won't lose your data anymore.

Or even use any other sql server that you would like, as long as you configure your database settings inside `settings.py` you should be fine, but while you are using local db, it will give you problems in production and deployment.

Hope this helps!